# Retriving only file name without extension but function error

Tags: php, regex, format

I have an url which contains various POST-DATA in it And an image file at last.
My example link is : `http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=565dbca63791e5.87676354.png`

I want to seperate the `565dbca63791e5.87676354.png` from the url and seperate the extension (.png) from it.

I have tried this:

```
<?php
  $images = array();
  $imagesNew = array();
  $imgUrls = array(
            'ptSignature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668695879dc84.35037895.png',
            'pSignature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668694f80aa55.79055562.png',
            'witness1Signature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668695875c6e5.03917128.png',
            'witness2Signature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668695879dc84.35037895.png',
        )


  function make_without_ext($str)
  {
    $regex = "/signature=(?<signature>[^&]+)/";
    preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);
    $signature = $matches["signature"];
    $ext = substr(strrchr($signature, '.'), 1);

    $without_extension = basename($signature, '.png');
    return $without_extension;
  }


  foreach ($imgUrls as $imgUrl) {
    $imgWithoutExt = make_without_ext($imgUrl);
    array_push($images, $imgWithoutExt);
  }

  foreach ($images as $image) {
    $content = file_get_contents($image);
    $data = base64_encode($content);
    array_push($imagesNew, $data) 
  }

  print '<pre>';
  print_r ($imagesNew);
  print '<pre>';
```

But it shows `syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION)`

Comment: PHP requires semicolons. You dropped one just before the `function`.

Answer (score 1):

What I do for things like this is use PHP's [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. Using your code, I would do something like this:

```
$str_parts = explode('.', $str);
$extension = array_pop($str_parts);
```

Note that this assumes you have a . in your string! Then you can just return your original string without this extension using substr or something. If signature is always the last parameter in your url, you could use the same technique to grab it if you wanted to although there are probably better ways to do that like using [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

better working example

```
<?php
$url = "http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=565dbca63791e5.87676354.png";

// to keep query only
$a = explode('&', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
$count = 0;
// looping parameters 
foreach($a as $as => $that){
    if(preg_match('|signature=|', $a[$count]) != false){ 
        // this is like, if this string is contained in this string do that 
        $b = trim($a[$count], 'signature='); // to remove the part we dont want
        $b = trim($b, '.png'); // again
        echo $b; // voilà!
    }

    $count++;
}
?>
```

I must confess this `foreach($a as $as => $that){` is kind of me trolling on a loop..

Comment: could you please paste full code?

Comment: if you copy/paste this code it is actually working.. and it is beautiful

Comment: Thanks for adding the working code sample @Raceimaztion. Interesting way to edit someone else's post ;)