# syntax error, unexpected 'function' on the line 12

Tags: php, regex, function

I have an url which contains various POST-DATA in it And an image file at last. My example link is : `http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=565dbca63791e5.87676354.png`

I want to seperate the `565dbca63791e5.87676354.png` from the url and seperate the extension (.png) from it.

I have tried this:

```
<?php
    $images = array();
    $imagesNew = array();
    $imgUrls = array(
                    'ptSignature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668695879dc84.35037895.png',
                    'pSignature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668694f80aa55.79055562.png',
                    'witness1Signature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668695875c6e5.03917128.png',
                    'witness2Signature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668695879dc84.35037895.png',
                )


    function make_without_ext($str)
        {
            $regex = "/signature=(?<signature>[^&]+)/";

            preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);
            $signature = $matches["signature"];
            $ext = substr(strrchr($signature, '.'), 1);

            $without_extension = basename($signature, '.png');
            return $without_extension;
        }


    foreach ($imgUrls as $imgUrl) {
        $imgWithoutExt = make_without_ext($imgUrl);
        array_push($images, $imgWithoutExt);
    }

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $content = file_get_contents($image);
        $data = base64_encode($content);
        array_push($imagesNew, $data) 
    }

    print '<pre>';
    print_r ($imagesNew);
    print '<pre>';
```

But it shows `syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION)`

Comment: why do you post a exact duplicate post with different title?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235369/retriving-only-file-name-without-extension-but-function-error

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing semicolon after:

```
$imgUrls = array(
                    'ptSignature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668695879dc84.35037895.png',
                    'pSignature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668694f80aa55.79055562.png',
                    'witness1Signature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668695875c6e5.03917128.png',
                    'witness2Signature' => 'http://website-link.com/?page=gf_signature&signature=5668695879dc84.35037895.png',
                )
```

Putting a semicolon would fix the problem in question.